# Site VF page Lightning experience issue

Tags: lightning-experience, force.com-sites

I have created one VF page and added that in site,But if i open that site the VF page displays in classic mode.

I have added lightningStylesheets="true"  in VF page.Can you please suggest how i can fix this issue ? Do i need to add the SLDS completely?

Answer (score 0):

lightningStylesheets=true is enough for showing VF page in **Lightning Experience UI when viewed in Lightning Experience** or the Salesforce app.

> You can style most commonly used Visualforce components with the
>   lightningStylesheets attribute. However, some components differ
>   slightly in style from Lightning Experience. For example,
>   < apex:inputFile>, and some < apex:inputField> elements use the
>   browser’s default styling instead. Commonly used Visualforce
>   components that don’t require styling, such as < apex:form>,
>   < apex:outputText>, and < apex:param>, are still supported.
>
> To include custom SLDS components that aren’t part of the Visualforce
>   component library, use the < apex:slds/> tag with the code and the
>   lightningStylesheets attribute.

So true with adding **< apex:slds/>**. It should show page in Lightning Experience UI when you open page in lightning mode.

Check [Style Existing Visualforce Pages with Lightning Experience Stylesheets](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/vf_dev_best_practices_slds_lightningstylesheets.htm)
 for more detail.